# What is the appropriate xml format to save a BPMN business process?

Tags: bpel, bpmn, workflow-engine

I want to save the a BPMN model into an executable XML format. What to choose between XPDL,BPEL,BPMN 2.0 XML. The XML file is going to be executed by a workflow engine.

Comment: Now that BPMN also allows execution with the version 2.0, most of software vendors using the XPDL standard are being phased out.
From what i found on the internet it looks like BPMN 2.0 is currently used for both modeling and execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The executable format you need will depend on what the workflow engine you use understands. Having said that: the only format in which you really can "save" the BPMN model without loosing or modifying some of your BPMN execution semantics is BPMN XML, because it's directly defined in the BPMN spec and therefore you don't have any mapping issues in between formats. Nowadays, the process engines of the bigger commercial vendors (IBM, Oracle, SAP) support BPMN XML, and the Open Source process engines in the Java space (Activiti, Bonita BPM, Camunda BPM, jBPM) support it, too.

Comment: Martin have you any useful links for articles that campares the xml formats with some statistics

Comment: @Deli, no sorry, nothing at hand, would have to make a deeper google research myself.

Comment: Just want to add that among Open Source process engines [Bonita BPM](http://www.bonitasoft.com/) also support [import](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/import-and-export-process-1#import)/[export](http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/import-and-export-process-1#export) of BPMN 2.0 XML.

Comment: @AntoineMottier I've added Bonita BPM to the text of my answer.